# How do I dynamically create string containing array variable?

Tags: php, arrays, string

Say I have the following array:

```
$baseData = [
    ['row1col1','row1col2','row1col3','row1col4','row1col5','row1col6'],
    ['row2col1','row2col2','row2col3','row2col4','row2col5','row2col6'],
    ['row3col1','row3col2','row3col3','row3col4','row3col5','row3col6'],
    ['row4col1','row4col2','row4col3','row4col4','row4col5','row4col6'],
    ...
];
```

I want to create a string of variables that can be used to merge existing array values into a new value.  In this example, I'm trying to get the value from columns 1,4,5 to merge together into one result for each "row" of the array.  For each "row" of the array, the result would be 'row1col1row1col4row1col5' ... or ... 'row3col1row3col4row3col5'.  I've tried doing the following which doesn't work.

```
//identify columns to be merged
$mergeColumns = Array('col1', 'col4','col5');

$mergePattern = '';
foreach($mergeColumns as $col) {
    $mergePattern .= "{$row['".$col."']}";
    }
//expected result: $mergePattern = "{$row['col1']}{$row['col4']}{$row['col5']}"

foreach($baseData as &$row) {
        $row['merged'] = $mergePattern;
    }
```

It's not working because the $row variable is being evaluated at the time that the $mergePattern variable is being formed.  I'm getting the error: *Undefined variable: row*.

**QUESTION:** How do I form the pattern in the first iteration so that it can be evaluated in the second iteration.

Comment: What is the value of `$col` ? And since when is `foreach( in )` a thing?

Comment: Can you describe the output you want from this code? You've said "I want it do this.." and then posted code that doesn't work, so it's very hard to understand what you want.

Comment: I'm not quite sure, is this what you want: http://3v4l.org/2m9FF ?

Comment: Sorry @Passerby.  I'm trying to merge two or more columns of an array into one new column.

Comment: @yajasi Yes, isn't that what my code does? In the "output" tag, you can see there's one new "merged" column.

Comment: @Passerby Can you post your code again.  I don't see it.

Comment: @Passerby Sorry that was obvious and I missed it.  Thanks.  Yes that is the result I'm looking for.